# On the syntactic distribution of ablative gerund and nominative present participle

Tags: classical-latin, syntax, participle, gerund

I've always taken it for granted that in Classical Latin nominative present participles cannot be replaced by ablative gerunds without a meaning change. For example, in the following case the replacement of *scribens* by *scribendo* (*Plato scribendo est mortuus*) would give an odd manner/means interpretation: 'Plato died ??{by/through...} writing'.

> Plato *scribens* est mortuus (Cic. *Sen.* 13)  'Plato died {writing/while he was writing}'.

However, I got a bit surprised when I read the following example from Tacitus, which involves a coordination of a present participle (*adsurgens*) with a gerund (*populando*).

> Incendium in edita *adsurgens* **et** rursus inferiora *populando* anteiit remedia (Tac. *Ann.* 15.38.4) 'By climbing up to the higher places and once more destroying the lower parts, the fire outstripped the firefighting'.

It seems to me that such an explicit coordination between a nominative present participle and an ablative gerund would **not** be allowed by ("more") classical authors like Cicero or Caesar. Is this intuition correct?

I was wondering if that example by Tacitus could be interpreted in the sense that a syntactic change (i.e. replacement of a nominative present participle by an ablative gerund) was taking place by that time. Or did it already take place before (e.g. are there any instantiations of this change in colloquial and/or technical Latin? As pointed out above, I'd be surprised to find examples of the previous coordination in Cicero or Caesar)?

Comment: The article mentioned by d_e seems very useful (Nutting, Herbert C. (1926). "The Ablative Gerund as a Present Participle." _The Classical Journal_ 22.2: 131-134). Many thanks for your post, d_e! By the way, why did you decide to hide it? Like you, I did find it _dignum dictu_!

Comment: Glad you find it useful. I like it much better in a comment as you did. This is a short article; eventually I find I want to include the article in its entirety for otherwise it felt wrong for me and any 'summery' is doing injustice. I salute the author for this! My opinion of course.

Comment: I'm not convinced you've analyzed this situation properly. Tacitus is commonly known to have utilized *inconcinnitas*, [especially in the *Annals*](https://epublications.marquette.edu/theses/1385/). You can do the same in English, e.g. "Holding town halls and through the writing of many letters, I managed to galvanize the populace." It's probably a deliberate choice rather than indicative of some shift.

Comment: @cmw As I see it, the issue here is not just a mere matter of "style". E.g. cf. also Vester (1991: 305): "In most grammars it is stated that there is a functional overlap between the present participle and the ablative of the gerund, at least **at a certain stage** in their development (…) it can be argued that in literary prose texts the present participle is not very desententialized; it has, in other words, a relatively low degree of embedding. The ablative of the gerund on the other hand is much more embedded. **But from Livy onwards**, and even in earlier non-literary texts...

Comment: **But from Livy onwards**, and even in earlier non-literary texts the ablative of gerund is clearly less embedded, at least in some cases; it often has no strict semantic function, but a (vague) circumstantial one, and this use simply increases in later vulgar texts. The implication of this fact is that **at a certain point in time** a rivalry between Praedicativum and ablative of the gerund comes into existence, since they do not differ any longer as far as embedding or clause linkage are concerned.

Comment: This rivalry could have been the right moment for a redistribution of the present participle and gerund" (Bold mine). As you can see, I'm interested in this _grammatical_ "rivalry" between these two categories (which, as noted above, does not exclude your correct _stylistic_ observations on Tacitus’s _inconcinnitas_. BTW, many thanks for this 1966 reference). Source: Vester, Elseline (1991). "Reflections on the gerund and gerundive". In Robert Coleman (ed.). _New Studies in Latin Linguistics_. 295-310. Amsterdam/Philadelphia: John Benjamins.